# Jquery - How to change from TABLE TD with TAB or ENTER Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, blur

I've a Jquery code that will edit a table cell, so I can input a value. The action is terminated by pressing the Key TAB or clicking another table TD.

I need to add the ENTER key so the action can be terminated.

My code:

```
$(function(){
    var message_status = $("#status");
    $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){

        console.log("You have pressed TAB key or clicked on another TD");

    });
});

<table class="tg">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td  contenteditable="true"></td>
      </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'terminated'? Exiting the 'editing' mode, preventing the user tabbing to another `<td>`, something else?

Comment: @DavidThomas it's not necessary to know what he means by "terminated", all we really need to know is that he wants to trigger that "termination" action when pressing enter, tab or bluring away

Answer (score 0):

One of the way could be also listening for a key press and when you hit enter (key code 13) while being focused in a cell, you will trigger the blur function.

```
$("td[contenteditable=true]").on("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        $(this).trigger("blur");
}).blur(function(){
    ...
```